# Split Date and Time in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a **DATETIME** column in `DataGridView`, which contains both the date and the time.  I need to separate the date from the time.  The date should be displayed in one column and the time in another column.

I've tried something but it just gives either the date only or the time only; however, I needed them both separately.

Comment: Without seeing your code, its hard to give an accurate answer. If its a `DateTime` data type, you can use `.ToShortDateString()` or `.ToShortTimeString()` to get the date or time.

Comment: Your last sentence is very confusing...you get date only and time only, but your need both separately....???

Answer (score 2):

You may format the cells of a column:

`dataGridView.Columns[#].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";`
`dataGridView.Columns[#].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm";`

Replace `#` with target columns.

All of the regular `DateTime` formatting options are available for the above example.  You may tailor it to your needs.  To review the available options, refer to MSDN's [Custom Date and Time Formatting Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation page.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do (example):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

string date = dt.ToShortDateString();
string time = dt.ToShortTimeString();
```

Then, insert into corresponding `DataGridView`'s cell:

```
dataGridView1[0, 1].Value = date;
dataGridView1[0, 2].Value = time;
```

Comment: Since it's a `DataGridView`, I doubt that he's basing his data of a single variable... in which case, this solution would be too much work.  Formatting the cell values is an easier, more elegant solution.

Comment: Definitely, your proposed solution is the perfect in this case, (you've got a +1 from me)

Comment: It's not possible to sort the date column if you convert it to string.